# php and mysql issue with query return

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this code working but only halfway, it is able to return all of the information that I need however on the return, one of the JSON array is returned twice, why is this? I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is my code:

```php
$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $array[$i] = (int)$row[0] . "\n";
    $i++;
    if ($i > $rows){
        break;
    }
}

$JsonArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){

    $q = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email from $mysql_database.$UsersTable WHERE idUser = $array[$i]";
    $res = mysql_query($q, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
    }
    $JsonArray[$i] = $new_array;                   
}

echo json_encode($JsonArray);
```

This is the result:

All I need is the second and third but somehow I don't know why it is outputting the first twice.
Also, how can I format the result better in the JsonArray?

Comment: Can you show the result of `print_r($JsonArray)`

Comment: Please format your code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are trying to do, you are trying to fetch your result set from the database for the query.

You need not make use of all those loops. All you have to do is:

```
$q = "SELECT firstName,lastName,email from $mysql_database.$UsersTable WHERE idUser=$array[$i]"; 
$res = mysql_query($q,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$new_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
mysqli_free_result($res);
```

You do not need that while loop for each row.

Comment: hi your right but I am still having the same output

Comment: After this line $new_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

Add this code: mysqli_free_result($res); Tell me if it works